# Raku / Perl6: A module to enable escape codes in the win32 console, naming suggestions

Tags: modules, raku

I have this little project i am about to release.

https://github.com/holli-holzer/perl6-Win-VT

I would be happy about a code review and suggestions for a better name.

Discussion in IRC yielded Terminal::Win::VT or Terminal::Win32::VT::Enable as better alternatives. Or even Win32::Console::VT.

This is the gist of it. There are additional files, but those provide just sugar.

```
unit module Win::VT;

use NativeCall;

constant STD_INPUT_HANDLE                   = -0xA;
constant STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE                  = -0xB;
constant ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_INPUT      = 0x0200;
constant ENABLE_PROCESSED_INPUT             = 0x0001;
constant ENABLE_PROCESSED_OUTPUT            = 0x0001;
constant ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING = 0x0004;
constant DWORD  := uint32;
constant BOOL   := int32;
constant HANDLE := Pointer[void];

sub GetConsoleMode(HANDLE, DWORD is rw) is native('Kernel32') returns BOOL { * };
sub SetConsoleMode(HANDLE, DWORD) is native('Kernel32') returns BOOL { * };
sub GetStdHandle(DWORD) is native('Kernel32') returns HANDLE { * };

my HANDLE $input-handle;
my HANDLE $output-handle;
my DWORD $output-mode;
my DWORD $input-mode;

INIT {
    if $*VM.osname eq "mswin32"
    {
        $input-handle  = GetStdHandle( STD_INPUT_HANDLE );
        $output-handle = GetStdHandle( STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE );
    }
}

sub vt-on(Bool :$vt-input=True, Bool :$vt-output=True ) returns Bool is export(:MANDATORY)
{
    return False
        unless $input-handle.defined && $output-handle.defined;

    return False
        unless GetConsoleMode($input-handle,  $input-mode) && GetConsoleMode($output-handle, $output-mode);

    my $new-input-mode  = $input-mode  +| ENABLE_PROCESSED_INPUT  +| ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_INPUT;
    my $new-output-mode = $output-mode +| ENABLE_PROCESSED_OUTPUT +| ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING;

    return (
        ( $vt-input  ?? SetConsoleMode($input-handle, $new-input-mode)  !! 1 ) &&
        ( $vt-output ?? SetConsoleMode($output-handle, $new-output-mode) !! 1 )
    ).Bool;
}

sub vt-off() returns Bool is export(:MANDATORY) {
    return (
        $input-handle.defined && $output-handle.defined &&
        SetConsoleMode($output-handle, $output-mode) &&
        SetConsoleMode($input-handle, $input-mode)
    ).Bool;
}

sub cls() is export(:cls) {
    vt-on;
    print chr(27) ~ '[2J' ~ chr(27) ~ '[;H';
    vt-off;
}
```

Comment: `*::ANSI` maybe?  The VT series may have introduced these codes but they were formalized by an ANSI spec and most people would call them "ANSI escape sequences" today.  Also `chr(27)` seems like it should be a constant.

Answer (score 4):

Since no one else has replied, here's somewhat of a ["rubber duck code review"](https://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/374098-any-thoughts-on-rubber-duck-code-reviews/) given that I don't know much about Windows, vt, and NativeCall. Plus I've got a suggestion about the API and module name.

---

It looks like the not-explicitly-initialized `$input-mode` and `$output-mode` variables are actually constants implicitly initialized to zero. I think the code would be less confusing if they were declared as constants or even if you used literal `0`s instead of them. Perhaps other code or configuration you have, or have in mind, will vary these values? Anyhow, at the very least, I think a comment making it clear the values the user passes to `vt-on` don't alter these, and `vt-off` is resetting them no matter what `vt-on` did, would be helpful.

---

From an API perspective, aiui, if one calls `vt-on` it turns the vt stuff on for both input and output. You have to pass `:vt-input(False)` if you only want `vt-output` and vice-versa. And `vt-off` always turns both off.

To me, having to write `vt-input(False)` is a bit ugly because:

- It repeats the `vt`;
- Mentions `input` when what one is trying to do is control `output`;
- Requires explicit use of `False`.

It seems to me it could be more ergonomic to have just one routine, `vt`. To switch both input and output on use `vt :on`. To switch both off use `vt :off`. To switch just one on and leave the other as it is, use `vt :on<input>` or `vt :on<output>`. To switch just one *off* and leave the other as it is, use `vt :off<input>` or `vt :off<output>`.

I've never used vt stuff and could imagine one doesn't need the extra flexibility of the API I suggest but my suggestion is really more about keeping the API sweet than it is about the additional flexibility.

---

As for the module name...

I currently think we should shift all of our emphasis related to module *discovery* to an assumption of widespread use of global search via keywords, tags, etc. For now that means eg ['terminal' tag search](https://modules.perl6.org/t/TERMINAL) or ['terminal' keyword search](https://modules.perl6.org/search/?q=TERMINAL) but one day there'll surely be search of a module's Pod and other aspects as well. In summary, imo, don't worry about a name's *discoverability*.

To the degree that a module's name matters, I think it's beyond discoverability. I think the two key things are considering clustering with names already chosen or likely to be chosen by other module authors, and making a name nice in a `use` statement. For these latter aspects I'd say:

- Consider following *accepted hierarchical namespace norms* already established for [modules.perl6.org](https://modules.perl6.org/). But don't sweat it.
- If there are no obvious relevant norms to follow then keep a module name fairly short and sweet. Do you really need bumpy case or hyphens? Do you really need more than one `::` divider? Then again, don't pick something egregiously short-sighted. You could name it just `VT` but a module such as yours doesn't warrant such a name.

---

Other than that the code all makes sense to me and looks fine to me from a pure P6 perspective.